# How to map a unique number to each unique string in a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas dataframe, I have a column where each row contains a list of strings. For each unique string in, I would like to assign a unique number.

If possible, I would like to assign a unique number to each unique string in multiple columns.

Here's a minimal example:

Setting up the initial pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': ['2f4', '1k1', 'nmk'], 'B': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
df.at[0, 'B'] = ['jki', 'gg4', 'k6k']
df.at[1, 'B'] = ['2f4', 'gg4', 'g24']
df.at[2, 'B'] = ['1k1', 'g24', '1k1']
```

will look like this

```
df

     A                B
0  2f4  [jki, gg4, k6k]
1  1k1  [2f4, gg4, g24]
2  nmk  [1k1, g24, 1k1]
```

I am looking for the result to be something like

```
     A                B  MappedA    MappedB
0  2f4  [jki, gg4, k6k]        0  [3, 4, 5]
1  1k1  [2f4, gg4, g24]        1  [0, 4, 6]
2  nmk  [1k1, g24, 1k1]        2  [1, 6, 1]
```

Each string has a unique number, starting at 0. If a string occurs again, the first assigned number is used again.

I found solutions where the column just has a string or number such as this

[Assign unique id to columns pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283086/assign-unique-id-to-columns-pandas-data-frame)

But I could not find any solutions where the column contains a list of values.

Edit:

A clarification, the length of the lists in column b are variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `pandas.factorize` and `numpy.split`

```
i, u = pd.factorize([*df.A, *np.concatenate(df.B)])
l = df.B.str.len()[:-1].cumsum()
n = len(df)

df.assign(MappedA=i[:n], MappedB=np.split(i[n:], l))

     A                B  MappedA    MappedB
0  2f4  [jki, gg4, k6k]        0  [3, 4, 5]
1  1k1  [2f4, gg4, g24]        1  [0, 4, 6]
2  nmk  [1k1, g24, 1k1]        2  [1, 6, 1]
```

---

#### Explanation

1. factorize all of column `'A'` and `'B'` together
2. find the length of lists in `'B'` because they'll help define where to split the resulting array
3. Take the first `n` belonging to `'MappedA'`
4. Take the rest and split according to calculated lengths.

---

#### Variable Lengths

Assume we had this `df` instead

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': ['2f4', '1k1', 'nmk'], 'B': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
df.at[0, 'B'] = ['jki', 'gg4', 'k6k']
df.at[1, 'B'] = ['2f4', 'gg4', 'g24']
df.at[2, 'B'] = ['1k1', 'g24', '1k1', 'pir']

df

     A                     B
0  2f4       [jki, gg4, k6k]
1  1k1       [2f4, gg4, g24]
2  nmk  [1k1, g24, 1k1, pir]
```

Then the same solution results in

```
i, u = pd.factorize([*df.A, *np.concatenate(df.B)])
l = df.B.str.len()[:-1].cumsum()
n = len(df)

df.assign(MappedA=i[:n], MappedB=np.split(i[n:], l))

     A                     B  MappedA       MappedB
0  2f4       [jki, gg4, k6k]        0     [3, 4, 5]
1  1k1       [2f4, gg4, g24]        1     [0, 4, 6]
2  nmk  [1k1, g24, 1k1, pir]        2  [1, 6, 1, 7]
```

Comment: what if the length of the lists in column B are variable?

Comment: This should handle that gracefully.  I account for it with `df.B.str.len()[:-1].cumsum()` for splitting later.

Comment: I'm guessing that the items in Column A will be mapped first? Or is that not guaranteed?