# Most computationally efficient way to map a unique number to each unique string in a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up to this question

[How to map a unique number to each unique string in a column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232129/how-to-map-a-unique-number-to-each-unique-string-in-a-column-of-lists/52232147?noredirect=1#comment91413695_52232147)

Which asks how to map a unique number to items across multiple pandas columns containing lists.

The solution given seems to be very slow when the number of items (total of items in column A and column B) is in the range of ~40 million. I have found some ways that can assign unique numbers to datasets for ~40 million items faster, but none quite for the situation of multiple columns , one of which contains a list.

Here was the minimal example and solution from the link above:

Setting up the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': ['2f4', '1k1', 'nmk'], 'B': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
df.at[0, 'B'] = ['jki', 'gg4', 'k6k']
df.at[1, 'B'] = ['2f4', 'gg4', 'g24']
df.at[2, 'B'] = ['1k1', 'g24', '1k1', 'pir']

df

     A                     B
0  2f4       [jki, gg4, k6k]
1  1k1       [2f4, gg4, g24]
2  nmk  [1k1, g24, 1k1, pir]
```

Solution

```
i, u = pd.factorize([*df.A, *np.concatenate(df.B)])
l = df.B.str.len()[:-1].cumsum()
n = len(df)

df.assign(MappedA=i[:n], MappedB=np.split(i[n:], l))

     A                     B  MappedA       MappedB
0  2f4       [jki, gg4, k6k]        0     [3, 4, 5]
1  1k1       [2f4, gg4, g24]        1     [0, 4, 6]
2  nmk  [1k1, g24, 1k1, pir]        2  [1, 6, 1, 7]
```

I am trying to see if there's a more computationally efficient solutions. I suspect this is so because there are methods than can assign unique numbers to ~40 million items with in a few minutes (where as the solution above never seems to complete).

Here is one such solution

```
mapping = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(df.A.unique())}  
df['MappedA'] = df.A.map(mapping)
```

I am wondering if there's a way to somehow apply this to my situation, where the items in column A and column B are mapped to unique numbers, starting at 0, with the items in column A getting the first numbers, then assigning leftover unique items in column B.

Edit:

A user mentioned that pandas is not the most computationally efficient way for dealing with lists of strings. I can convert this to a numpy array via

```
numpyArray = df.values
```

So if there's a way to work the solution with numpy arrays it can be implemented very easily.

Comment: If you're interested in computationally efficient you shouldn't be storing lists of strings in a DataFrame

Comment: Perhaps just numpy arrays then? If the data was stored of numpy arrays, do you know of a solution? I'll update the question to include this situation.

Comment: You're just storing a numpy array of lists then, which still isn't particularly efficient.

Comment: What would be the best way to handle this type of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inefficiency comes from the latitude I took to construct various portions.  I can improve performance with a few tweaks

```
a = df.A.values
b = np.concatenate(df.B.values)
i, u = pd.factorize(np.append(a, b))
l = np.array([*map(len, df.B)])[:-1].cumsum()
n = len(df)

df.assign(MappedA=i[:n], MappedB=np.split(i[n:], l))
```

For a bigger `df`

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
%%timeit
i, u = pd.factorize([*df.A, *np.concatenate(df.B)])
l = df.B.str.len()[:-1].cumsum()
n = len(df)

df.assign(MappedA=i[:n], MappedB=np.split(i[n:], l))

# 1 loop, best of 3: 506 ms per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
a = df.A.values
b = np.concatenate(df.B.values)
i, u = pd.factorize(np.append(a, b))
l = np.array([*map(len, df.B)])[:-1].cumsum()
n = len(df)

df.assign(MappedA=i[:n], MappedB=np.split(i[n:], l))

# 10 loops, best of 3: 95.1 ms per loop
```

That gets us a 5x improvement.